# Reading from a text file then splitting that information

Tags: python

I need to read from a text file, then print the information separately. 
for example:
i'm given a list of names in this format: Orville Wright 21 July 1988
And i need to make the outcome as so:
Name
    1. Orville Wright
Date
    1. 21 July 1988

I've tried using a reader to separate but I would have to have a separate code line for every name and date given as they are not the same length.

`````````````````````````````````````````````````````
with open('File name and location', 'r') as reader:
    print(reader.readline(14))

``````````````````````````````````````````````````  
this is the outcome : Orville Wright
```````````````````````````````````````````````````

I want my results to be:

Name:
     1. Orville Wright
     2. Rogelio Holloway
     etc
Date:
     1. 21 July 1988
     2. 13 September 1988
     etc
````````````````````````````````````````````````````
The contents of the file are as follows:
Orville Wright 21 July 1988
Rogelio Holloway 13 September 1988
Marjorie Figueroa 9 October 1988
Debra Garner 7 February 1988
Tiffany Peters 25 July 1988
Hugh Foster 2 June 1988
Darren Christensen 21 January 1988
Shelia Harrison 28 July 1988
Ignacio James 12 September 1988
Jerry Keller 30 February 1988
Frankie Cobb 1 July 1988
Clayton Thomas 10 December 1988
Laura Reyes 9 November 1988
Danny Jensen 19 September 1988
Sabrina Garcia 20 October 1988
Winifred Wood 27 July 1988
Juan Kennedy 4 March 1988
Nina Beck 7 May 1988
Tanya Marshall 22 May 1988
Kelly Gardner 16 August 1988
Cristina Ortega 13 January 1988
Guy Carr 21 June 1988
Geneva Martinez 5 September 1988
Ricardo Howell 23 December 1988
Bernadette Rios 19 July 1988
`````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Comment: Can you show us the contents of the file?

Comment: I added the contents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one approach using regex.

**Ex:**

```
import re

names = []
dates = []
with open(filename) as infile:
    for line in infile:
        line = line.strip()
        date = re.search("(\d{1,2} [a-zA-Z]+ \d{4})", line).group(1)  #Extract Date. 
        dates.append(date) 
        names.append(line.replace(date, "").strip())  #Get Name. 

print("Name:")
for name in names:
    print(name)
print("---"*10)
print("Date:")
for date in dates:
    print(date)
```

**Output:**

```
Name:
Orville Wright
Rogelio Holloway
Marjorie Figueroa
Debra Garner
Tiffany Peters
Hugh Foster
Darren Christensen
Shelia Harrison
Ignacio James
Jerry Keller
Frankie Cobb
Clayton Thomas
Laura Reyes
Danny Jensen
Sabrina Garcia
Winifred Wood
Juan Kennedy
Nina Beck
Tanya Marshall
Kelly Gardner
Cristina Ortega
Guy Carr
Geneva Martinez
Ricardo Howell
Bernadette Rios
------------------------------
Date:
21 July 1988
13 September 1988
9 October 1988
7 February 1988
25 July 1988
2 June 1988
21 January 1988
28 July 1988
12 September 1988
30 February 1988
1 July 1988
10 December 1988
9 November 1988
19 September 1988
20 October 1988
27 July 1988
4 March 1988
7 May 1988
22 May 1988
16 August 1988
13 January 1988
21 June 1988
5 September 1988
23 December 1988
19 July 1988
```

Answer (score 0):

Store all the names and dates inside different lists, then display each one.

The following code assumes that each name & date are separated by a newline, and that the first digit in that line is the start of the date.

```py
import re

names = []
dates = []
with open('File name and location', 'r') as reader:
    for line in reader.readlines():
        date_position = re.search("\d", line).start()
        names.append(line[:date_position - 1])
        dates.append(line[date_position:])
```

Now you can print each name and date to your liking:

```py
for i, name in enumerate(names):
    print(f"{i+1}. {name}")
```

And for dates:

```py
for i, date in enumerate(dates):
    print(f"{i+1}. {name}")
```

Output (for part of the text file):

```
1. Orville Wright
2. Rogelio Holloway
3. Marjorie Figueroa
4. Debra Garner
5. Tiffany Peters
6. Hugh Foster
7. Darren Christensen
8. Shelia Harrison
9. Ignacio James
10. Jerry Keller
11. Frankie Cobb
12. Clayton Thomas
13. Laura Reyes
14. Danny Jensen
15. Sabrina Garcia
16. Winifred Wood
17. Juan Kennedy
1. 21 July 1988

2. 13 September 1988

3. 9 October 1988

4. 7 February 1988

5. 25 July 1988

6. 2 June 1988

7. 21 January 1988

8. 28 July 1988

9. 12 September 1988

10. 30 February 1988

11. 1 July 1988

12. 10 December 1988

13. 9 November 1988

14. 19 September 1988

15. 20 October 1988

16. 27 July 1988

17. 4 March 1988
```

Comment: I did update my question with the contents, but incase it is still uploading the format for each line is:   Orville Wright 21 July 1988

Comment: My answer works for your text file, assuming all dates start with a digit (and names do not contain digits).